# Add `current WS connection number` metric

Tags: prometheus

I see the node provides a metrics port to be used with prometheus, just want to check whether can add a new metrics to provide the current ws connection number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: the snippet of the `curl` below I think has the specific metrics to look at. I *think* what you want is `substrate_rpc_sessions_opened - substrate_rpc_sessions_closed`**

You can see all metrics included following [the data viz tutorial](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/edit/main/v3/tutorials/06-node-metrics/index.mdx):

- Install Prometheus [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/).
- Install OSS Grafana [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/download?edition=oss).

Substrate exposes an endpoint which serves metrics in the [Prometheus exposition
format](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/) available on port
`9615`. You can change the port with `--prometheus-port <PORT>` and enable it to
be accessed over an interface other than local host with
`--prometheus-external`.

```bash
# Optionally add the `--prometheus-port <PORT>`
# or `--prometheus-external` flags
./target/release/node-template --dev
```

#### Configure Prometheus to scrape your Substrate node

In the working directory where you installed Prometheus, you will find a `prometheus.yml` configuration file.
Let's modify this (or create a custom new on) to configure Prometheus to scrape the exposed endpoint by adding
it to the targets array. If you modify the default, here is what will be different:

```yml
# --snip--

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'substrate_node'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    # ** NOTE: you want to have this *LESS THAN* the block time in order to ensure
    # ** that you have a data point for every block!
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9615']
```

Now we can start a Prometheus instance with the prometheus.yml config file. Presuming you downloaded the binary,
`cd` into the install directory and run:

```bash
# specify a custom config file instead if you made one here:
./prometheus --config.file prometheus.yml
```

leave this process running.

#### Check All Prometheus Metrics

In a new terminal, we can do a quick status check on prometheus:

```bash
curl localhost:9615/metrics
```

Which should return a similar output to:

```bash
# HELP substrate_rpc_requests_finished Number of RPC requests (not calls) processed by the server.
# TYPE substrate_rpc_requests_finished counter
substrate_rpc_requests_finished{protocol="ws",chain="dev"} 36
# HELP substrate_rpc_requests_started Number of RPC requests (not calls) received by the server.
# TYPE substrate_rpc_requests_started counter
substrate_rpc_requests_started{protocol="ws",chain="dev"} 36
# HELP substrate_rpc_sessions_closed Number of persistent RPC sessions closed
# TYPE substrate_rpc_sessions_closed counter
substrate_rpc_sessions_closed{chain="dev"} 1
# HELP substrate_rpc_sessions_opened Number of persistent RPC sessions opened
# TYPE substrate_rpc_sessions_opened counter
substrate_rpc_sessions_opened{chain="dev"} 2
```

Alternatively in a browser open that same URL (http://localhost:9615/metrics) to view
all available metric data.

> Here you can see the `HELP` fields for each metric that is exposed for monitoring via Grafana.
> Visualizing Prometheus Metrics with Grafana is not required, but quite powerful!